# iOS swift: scrollview does not call didscrolltotop

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Evening: I have a scroll view with 3 views inside..

I have a problem with the scrollview delegates.

The didscrolltotop is never called, while the did scroll yes...

I can't understand the reason...

Any help?

[image]

Comment: Is the `scrollsToTop` property set, as per that method's documentation?

Comment: yes, it is, in the viewdidload

Comment: Can you provide an MCVE?  Right now we can only guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is only called under certain circumstances, the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619382-scrollviewdidscrolltotop) talks about the `scroll-to-top gesture` meaning it may only work after `a tap on the status bar` and not basic scrolling. Also setting the `scrollsToTop` property to `true` seems to be required.

> The scroll view sends this message when it finishes scrolling to the top of the content. It might call it immediately if the top of the content is already shown. For the scroll-to-top gesture (a tap on the status bar) to be effective, the scrollsToTop property of the UIScrollView must be set to YES.

You could also simply detect the top of the content using the `contentOffset`

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print("The current Y offset is \(scrollView.contentOffset.y)")
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0 {
        print("we are at the top")
    }
}
```

You might also want to consider using the [`scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619417-scrollviewdidenddecelerating) method for this as it will mean you only get one event after the scroll view has settled down.

Comment: Already saw that part... but it does not help me... scrolltotop is already to true

Comment: Sounds like you can't be doing something that it requires, have you tried using the `contentOffset` property?

Comment: I believe this is only called when tapping the status bar causes the scrollview to scroll to the top.

Comment: @wez is there a way to know if the user is trying to scroll up when is already at the top? i mean when the user is trying to go in -y or simply when the scroll bounce on top? because in that case i want to dismiss the view controller

Comment: You should receive a negative offset yes, might be worth `print()`ing out the content offset to see what you get out.. then write your code to handle the behaviour.